# Let $P(x)$ be any polynomial and suppose that $a_n \rightarrow a$. Prove $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(a_n) = P(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-verification

I know the limit rules but that's not helping me out much here this seems so simple but I don't even know where to start. I read the chapter on this and they don't do any examples like this.  I believe a sub n converges to a.

Comment: Can you show that $a_n^k\to a^k$ for all $k$? I would suggest to start with that.

Comment: do you already know anything about continuity? this would make things much less technical here.

Comment: @ Max Yes , I know about continuity. @ Andrew so its like a proof by induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, check (as you mentioned, by induction, or whatever method you prefer) that for all $k$, $a_n^k\to a^k$. For this, use that the limit of a product of the product of the limits.

Now, if $a_n^k\to a^k$, then also $ca_n^k\to ca^k$ for any constant $c$.

Finally, note that any polynomial is a sum of terms of that form, and use that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.

More carefully, if $P(x)=b+cx+dx^2+\dots+ex^m$, then $$P(a_n)=b+ca_n+da_n^2+\dots+ea_n^m,$$ and each term $ra_n^k$ converges to $ra^k$. So $P(a_n)$, being a sum of these terms, converges to $$b+ca+da^2+\dots+ea^m=P(a).$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, (as you know continuity), 
 the polynomial $P$ is a continuous function mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Sequential continuity coincides with continuity** in this case, then $a_n\to a$ implies $P(a_n)\to P(a)$.

See [sequential continuity and continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614333/continuity-and-sequential-continuity/708222#708222)

Comment: Why is it *clear* that polynomials are continuous?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Ruffini identity, which is connected to the Horner scheme, then you know that there exists a polynomial $q(a,x)$ such that
$$
p(x)=p(a)+(x-a)q(a,x)
$$
Now you need only to argue that $q(a,x)$ is bounded if the distance from $x$ to $a$ is bounded to get the estimate
$$
|p(x)-p(a)|\le M(r)\,|x-a| \quad\text{for}\quad |x-a|<r.
$$

Comment: One elementary way of verifying that there is such a polynomial $q$ is to note that $x^k-a^k=(x-a)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}a+\dots+xa^{k-2}+a^{k-1})$, so it is $(x-a)$ times a polynomial in $x$ and $a$. This is for each $k$, and $p(x)-p(a)$ is a sum of multiples of these differences. I thought about including this argument, but I suspect that the task of showing boundedness may be seen about as hard as the original question.

Comment: No, the bound is easy, just apply the triangle inequality to $|q(a,x)|$ to replace everything by their absolute values and then replace $|x|$ by $|a|+r$ to get the constant $M(r)$. -- If Horner-Ruffini is not known, then your answer shows the easier way.

Comment: I know it is easy, but then again, so is the question at hand. They feel comparable, is what I meant. By the way, I didn't know the identity was named after Ruffini.

Comment: There is a rather silly discussion on the wikipedia talk pages, if the two articles [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) and [Horner scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) should be merged or if they really are different topics. What I understand as a reasonable point of view is that the synthetic division formula is named for Ruffini, and the computation scheme for Horner, but there is a large area of overlapping content. The Horner article is by far the better written one.